# How to capture PowerShell Write-Progress text in child spawn process in node.js?

Tags: node.js, powershell, terminal, progress-bar, child-process

In node.js I create child processes like this for example

```
child_process.spawn('powershell.exe', ['-executionpolicy', 'remotesigned', '-File', 'save_site_login_web.ps1', data.app_catalogue_url, data.ids.join(",")], { windowsHide:true });

const handler = (data) => {
     // send data to client
};
    
watcher_shell.stdout.on('data', handler);
watcher_shell.stderr.on('data', handler);
```

However, in the child process, it displays a progress bar like this picture (I got this from running it manually from a powershell terminal). The area on top with the light blue background is static and stays on top, while the text in it updates.

[image]

However this progress text doesn't get captured in stdout or stderr. How can I capture this stream in node.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mklement0 stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66521631/7571258), the progress stream is not directly redirectable.

That being said, since Windows 1809+ there is the new pseudo console (ConPTY) API, which basically allows any program to act like the console, thus capturing output that is written directly to the console.

Doing a quick search, there is the [node-pty](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty) module which supposedly utilizes the ConPTY API on Windows. I haven't tried it but it looks promising (VS Code is using it for its integrated terminal).

Comment: This does capture the progress stream. I use npm module `ansi-to-html` to convert it to friendly HTML, but it seems it doesn't work so great when using node-pty. Do you know if there is another module for this one?

Comment: @omega I don't know. This was just the first search result for "node conpty".

Comment: Figured it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522517/how-to-convert-conpty-output-to-html/66534726#66534726

Answer (score 1):

[`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress) output isn't part of [PowerShell's system of output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), so it cannot be captured - neither in-session from PowerShell, nor externally via stdout or stderr.

From the linked *about_Redirection* help topic:

> There is also a Progress stream in PowerShell, but it does not support redirection.

[zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66521802/45375) shows a *workaround* on Windows that doesn't rely on PowerShell's features.